# Показывать в label значение из placeholder только если введен текст

Tags: jquery, input, placeholder

Добрый день! Хотелось бы использовать в своих формах что то похожее на это https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-required-fields

Кроме того что ошибка у нас выводиться не в поле, а рядом с полем в div и заполняется с помощью ajax запросов отправляемых при вводе пользователя и это переделывать не будем.

То есть имеем такую разметку:

```
<form id="regist_form" method="post" action="#">
{literal}
<script>
    $(function(){$("#login").nickmsk({ctype:"userlogin", fsetid: 0, msg: $("#login_msg"), min: 5 });});//навешивает на поле проверку ajax на лету. Менять это не будем.
</script>
{/literal}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="login" class="sr-only">
        Email<sup>*</sup>
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="email" value="" name="login" id="login" maxlength="400" class="formControl" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите email" autofocus/>
    </div>
    <div id="login_msg"></div> 
</div></form>
```

Нужно, что бы когда пользователь вводит текст в поле и плейсхолдер исчезает то в label было видно значение из плейсхолдер,  а иначе label был бы скрыт/пустой.
Хотелось бы что бы это работало не зависимо и не конфликтовало с проверкой на лету. Которая может вставить ошибку в div id="login_msg" если формат мейла не верный и возможно если поле не заполнено.

Comment: Непонятно, как тестировать ваш код: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: меняйте текст label при получении фокуса и потере. А разве гугл не предоставляет уже готовые компоненты?

Comment: А почему при получении фокуса, а не изменении содержимого поля?